Looking for name of pretty old movie where children take refuge in single tree because of flood
I remember watching this old looking movie. I only remember two scenes from it and for some reason the words "cast away" keep popping up every time I think about this movie. 
The first scene I remember is children (or young people) are stuck in a flood (or storm) and they are saved by a single tree in a desert. I remember seeing them cook egg fry and stuff using the eggs some birds laid on the tree.
The second scene I remember is the same group are caught by a tribe and then sent to this "prison" where there is only one other prisoner. He tells them that he made a rope out of his hair (i am not too sure about this part), and they can use it escape the prison because it is situation on a really tall rock or something. When they escape, he uses two stones to light the rope up so that the tribes people can't follow them.
I really want to know the name of this movie, because I loved it in the past. I hope that both these scenes are actually from the same movie and I am not confusing myself between two movies, haha.
UPDATE:
I remembered something else! The young people (or kids) were going on an adventure to find the person who sent a message-in-a-bottle...hope this helps...

Thanks for the detailed description, posted a match. For future reference, please try to include all the extra details you can remember like year, country etc.

Sounds like the Disney film In Search of the Castaways from 1962 with Maurice Chevalier, Hayley Mills and George Sanders.

An earthquake, a flash flood, an avalanche, a volcano, alligators, jaguars, mutineers, and a man-eating Maoris dog the steps of a shipping company owner, a scientist, and the two children of a lost sea captain as they circle the earth along the 37th parallel per instructions in a bottled note the scientist has recovered from a shark's stomach.

It contains all the scenes mentioned (the tree, the eggs, the prison, the hair rope burned by flints etc.) Based on a Jules Verne novel. Here are them frying the eggs:



